# Enhanced 'switch' blocks are not supported at language level '13' - Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, switch-statement

I'm trying to use switch lambda in my code

```
 switch (nilai){
            case "A" -> System.out.println("Anda lulus");
            default ->{System.out.println("gagal");}
        }
```

but I got an error message Enhanced 'switch' blocks are not supported at language level '13'
I've tried to update the SDK to version 15

[image]

And also for the module

[image]

There's no higher language level in the IDE

[image]

But it still give the same error message, what can I do to fix this?

I've looked and post in Stack, but it doesn't seem to work for me.
Thank you.

Comment: What's your IntelliJ version? Lambda expressions in switch statements were added in Java 14, so it looks like your IntelliJ version is too old and doesn't support Java 14.

Comment: Looking in the module settings for my current project I only have JDK 12, yet the language level dropdown shows language features out to JDK 15 (preview sealed types etc) so I suspect @dunni is correct.

Comment: @dunni I'm using version 2019.2.4(Community Edition)

Comment: @Gavin what version of Intellij are you using?

Comment: @Ronin7 version 2020.3.2 Ultimate.  Update to 2020.3.2 community addition and you should see the new language levels in the drop down for your project.  JetBrains release three major editions each "year" with the first one of the year coming out around March/April (so I would guess 2021.1 is due soon)

Comment: @Gavin thx, I'll try